# How to remove Nan's from a list and extend to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, nan, extend

I am trying to extend a list to a separate list of lists in it's correct order. But some of the values are Nan's. When I do this I get an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`. Would it be more efficient to iterate through the list removing Nan's and then extend to a list?

An example of the dataset and code is shown below:

Data:

```
X    Y
5    6
Nan  Nan
10   5
Nan  Nan
8    2

n=0
for column in data :
    if n == 0 :
        n+=1
        continue
    visuals[0].extend([float(column[0])])
    visuals[1].extend([float(column[1])])
```

Following on from the comments after @Mahesh Karia's code. The dummy data works fine but my dataset returns empty lists. An example of both is provided below:

```
data_1 = [['Nan', 5, 'Nan', 10, 'Nan', 8],
        ['Nan', 6, 'Nan', 5, 'Nan', 2]]

data_2 = [[nan, -5891.3764, -5901.0081390000005, -5939.977304, -5921.11797],
        [nan, 3339.025337, 3346.9211149999996, 3356.405148, 3412.836335]]
```

So data_1 works but data_2 returns an empty list?

Comment: What exactly is your original data? Show us its Python form, not the printout.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you would have to compare each list item to see if it is either the string `Nan` or an integer. What about creating a new list via list comprehension `[float(a) for a in x if a != 'Nan']` to filter out the `Nan`s from each given list (and convert the integers to a float) in one go?

Comment: Are you trying to take 2 lists and make a list of lists? If so there are straightforward ways of doing that.

Comment: `.append(item)` is more straightforward than `.extend([item])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        if str(s).lower() != "nan":
            float(s)
            return True
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return False


data_2 = [['nan', -5891.3764, -5901.0081390000005, -5939.977304, -5921.11797],
        ['nan', 3339.025337, 3346.9211149999996, 3356.405148, 3412.836335]]

visuals = [[],[]]

visuals[0].extend([float(_) for _ in data_2[0] if is_number(_)])
visuals[1].extend([float(_) for _ in data_2[1] if is_number(_)])

print visuals
```

**output:**

```
[[-5891.3764, -5901.0081390000005, -5939.977304, -5921.11797], [3339.025337, 3346.9211149999996, 3356.405148, 3412.836335]]
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense but your function works well with the dummy data but when I try to run it on my dataset it returns an empty list? There's definitely confirmed data in the original list so I can't understand why it won't work?

Comment: can you paste your data ?

Comment: I've provided an example of the dataset

Comment: @JPA0888 updated code and now even negative floats will be considered.

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh Karia but I was hoping to remove the nan's from the returned list.

Comment: @JPA0888 Oops made some changes, check now

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a list comprehension that removes all the nan values.

```
data = ['1', '2', "nan", '4']
[float(datum) for datum in data if datum != "nan"]
```

Which easily extends to lists of lists.

```
data = [['1', '2', 'nan', '4'], ['5', '6', 'nan']]
[[float(bar) for bar in foo if bar != "nan"] for foo in data]
```

Assuming of course that there's only one string value that you need to catch. If there's multiple you'll probably want to consider either a function that does custom handling, or a `try` statement.

Comment: This doesn't seem to take the `nan's` out. I've printed ` [[float(bar) for bar in foo if bar != 'nan'] for foo in data]` and the lists doesn't change.

Comment: Do the cases match? Try `bar.lower() != “nan”`

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution would be to wrap the float conversion in a try/except block:

```
for column in data:
    ...
    try:
        visuals[0].extend([float(column[0])])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: May have a similar to @Mahesh Karia's solution. It just returns an empty list?